# Formatting numbers like 10000 as 10k

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 5-digit number, like `10000`, and I want to display it as `10k`, as I'll eventually have 6 digits (I'm talking about Twitter counts, actually). I suppose I have to substring, but I'm not that used to JavaScript just yet.

Here's just about what I'm trying to use. It basically gets the count of the followers by JSON.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json',
            data: {
                screen_name: 'lolsomuchcom'
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
            $('#followers').html(data.followers_count);
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you used `toString()` and `substr()`?

Comment: `followers_count` is five numbers? And how exactly does this look like? Or how is your post to be understood? Please include a proper example, it's difficult to understand what your problem is.

Comment: You lost me at `eventually I'll have 6 numbers anyways`.

Comment: Last edit is titled "Improving code format."... actually you made it worse.

Comment: I'm still at a loss as to where these mysterious five numbers are.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot as in the 10,000s where it can soon reach 6, being 100,000 followers. But I'm basically trying to convert to using k for the thousand.

Comment: So you've got a number in the tens- or hundreds- of thousands. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Turning 39868 into 39K.

Comment: See, giving examples makes everything to much easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#followers').html(data.followers_count.substring(0, data.followers_count.length - 3));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWfPW/

Edit.. here's the literal code, just for you:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json',
        data: {
            screen_name: 'lolsomuchcom'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            // Ensure it's a string
            data.followers_count += '';
            $('#followers').html(data.followers_count.substring(0, data.followers_count.length - 3) + 'K');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Did you click the fiddle link? It works.

Comment: Yea, but it goes blank using this snippet.

Comment: There, even added the 'K' for you per your comment

Comment: Why not do it the "too simple" way?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I can say, you both do have right answers, and I do appreciate the help from the both of you. :)

Comment: String-handling to do something straightforwardly mathematical is bonkers.

Comment: Haha I wholeheartedly agree with @Beetroot-Beetroot. I had no idea what you were planning to do with your follower count until your last comment about turning 39868 into 39K. In the end, while both work, his answer makes sense and won't confuse future devs looking at your code base.

Comment: Eeek, you took the question too literally!

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
$('#followers').html(Math.floor(data.followers_count/1000) + 'K');
```

Comment: +1 in case this isn't accepted. It should be :)

Comment: @AlienWebguy, you are a string-handling gentleman sir.